# Extracting single digit numbers from a cell with mixed text

Tags: google-spreadsheets

I have a set of cells that have single digit rating numbers mixed with text next to them (ratings of 1 - 9). What I'd like to do is for each of the cells, extract the numbers and produce an average.  I know about functions like Search and RegexExtract, but I don't understand how to use them to get all the numbers as it seems to only return the first match.

Here is a sample of the text in a single cell:

```
A - 1
B - 5
C - 9
D -4
E -7
F -  2
```

For the above text, I'm looking to create an array {1,5,9,4,7,2} and pass that to the average function.

Also I'm using Google Sheets, but most of the standard Excel functions should work the same. Thanks.

Comment: All the text shown above is in a single cell, say A1.

Comment: Then the formula will be unique to Google Sheets, as the method to do this in Excel will not work in Google Sheets, and as such this question belongs on DevApps not here.

Comment: this may be more suitable on [webapps.se]

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is the `AVERAGE` of those values, in Sheets, try (with your data in A1:

```
=average(split(trim(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"\D+"," "))," "))
```

Instead of trying to extract each number, we merely remove the non-digits; then split and average them.  It is sometimes a handy technique to remove what we don't want, rather than trying to extract what we do want.

[image]

*For **Excel** users, if you have Excel 2016+ with the `TEXTJOIN` function, you can use this **array** formula:*

```
=AVERAGE(ABS(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,A1:A6)," ","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[number()=number()]")))
```

*Since this is an array formula, you need to "confirm" it by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.  If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula as observed in the formula bar*

Answer (score 1):

*I would like to suggest, two steps solution will fix the issue:*

## caveat:

- Below shown method is for Excel users, since VBA doesn't works for Google Sheet.
- Excel file can be converted into `XLSX` file format which is suitable/editable with  Google Sheet.
- `SUMPRODUCT` works with Google sheet also.

---

[image]

**Step 1:**

- Either press **A**lt+F11 or **R**ight Click the **S**heet TAB and from
  poped up menu hit **V**iew Code to get VB editor.
- **C**opy and **P**aste this code as **M**odule, then return to the Sheet.

  ```
  Public Function SplitNum(pWorkRng As Range, pIsNumber As Boolean) As String

  Dim xLen As Long
  Dim xStr As String
  xLen = VBA.Len(pWorkRng.Value)
  For i = 1 To xLen
  xStr = VBA.Mid(pWorkRng.Value, i, 1)
  If ((VBA.IsNumeric(xStr) And pIsNumber) Or (Not (VBA.IsNumeric(xStr)) And Not (pIsNumber))) Then
      SplitNum = SplitNum + xStr
  End If
   Next
  End Function
  ```
- Enter this formul in Cell `AI5`: `=SplitNum(AH1,TRUE)`

**Step 2:**

- To get **A**VERAGE enter this formula in Cell `AJ5`.

  ```
  =SUMPRODUCT(--MID(AI5,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(AI5))),1))/Len(AI5)
  ```

---

**Google Sheet users can use this formula:**

```
=AVERAGE(SPLIT(AH1,CONCATENATE(SPLIT(AH1,".0123456789"))))
```

---

**N.B.**
 - *Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: @fixer1234,, unable to get what exactly U are trying to say, please be specific!

Comment: @fixer1234,, now take a look, I've edited the post.